# Problem faced when trying to use Aws::S3 command in Ruby on Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

On trying to access the ' Aws::S3 ' command from Rails console the following error comes up not only this , I cannot use any other Aws module .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
       15: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
       14: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-
       12: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.53.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
       11: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-1.25.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms/types.rb:9:in `<module:KMS>'
        3: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-kms-1.25.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms/types.rb:27:in `<module:Types>'
        2: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-kms-1.25.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms/types.rb:27:in `new'
        1: from /home/shahbaz/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty/module_inheritable_attributes.rb:38:in `inherited'
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)
```

How can I solve this issue please help

Comment: whats your ruby and rails versions?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'  and ruby 2.6.5

Comment: this error tell us nothing, give us code which you are using to call AWS

Comment: which gem and version are you using?

Comment: @user6500179 gem 'aws-sdk' ,

Comment: @noname using in the rails console

Comment: I can easily google the answer for you problem, amazon have its own guide how to connect to AWS just google